# Getting correct NSDate value - is this the most efficient method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this code to get the local date/time. It works but it seems a long way around the bush (10 statements) to get my current date/time value rather than the GMT time.

```
NSDate          *currentDateGMT = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *currentDateDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone      *currentDateTimeZoneGMT = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

[currentDateDateFormatter setTimeZone: currentDateTimeZoneGMT];
[currentDateDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
[currentDateDateFormatter setLocale:locale];

NSString *currentDateString = [currentDateDateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDateGMT];
NSDate *currentDateAdjusted = [currentDateDateFormatter dateFromString:currentDateString]; 

[currentDateDateFormatter release];
```

Can someone confirm that this is the best way to obtain the current machine value?

Thanks

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the date? NSDate doesn't have a time zone, the "GMT" value you are seeing is just the description of an NSDate object, this is formatted to GMT. However the underlying value is the correct current time.

Comment: @jrturton is correct. You are not "adjusting" the date, you are just displaying it in a different timezone (offset).

Comment: Hi all: I'm using it to break it apart to capture the date components and to graft on a calculated time - x hours before an event starts. However, if that new event time has already passed, I use offsetComponents to roll over to the next day. Hope this helps and thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDateFormatter` will default to the users time zone so the simplest solution is

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//lower case h for hour will also default to the users
//12/24 hour clock preference
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"];

NSString *currentDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

[formatter release];
```

Comment: I already have a timezone adjusted date so I don't want have it adjusted at all. For example, if someone enters a time when they want an event to occur, I don't want it to be adjusted or thrown off after the fact. Thus, this statement "
NSTimeZone      *currentDateTimeZoneGMT = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
" to avoid having it adjusted for timezone. Thanks

Comment: @Jazzmine there's no such this as a "timezone adjusted date".  `[NSDate date]` *is* the current time, *regardless* of what timezone you're in. Timezones are only relevant when formatting a date for display.

Comment: Ok, help me understand what happened this afternoon. I ran my program at 12:30 p.m. CST and NSDate gave me 18:30 for the time. Was it giving me true GMT time which is six hours different from my location? I really wanted/expected to see 12:30 p.m. Thanks for your patience in explaining this to me.

Comment: Dave: I think I understand what you are saying - NSDate returns the true and only time. I can use GMT to get my adjust time for display?

Comment: NSDate returns the "true" time. If we both run programs calling [NSDate date] at exactly the same time (for example because we are talking on the phone and press a button at the exact same moment), we'll get the exact same result, even though the watch on your hand says you called the method on the 16th, 11pm, while the watch on my hand says I called it on the 17th, 5am in the morning. (This is dangerous for British developers because there is a chance that bugs in their code are invisible for six months; US developers will notice immediately something is wrong).